# Unknown process in Ubuntu running two cores at 100% load

Tags: cpu-usage, ubuntu-18.04

I have two different computers, running Ubuntu 18.04

Both computers have two cores running at 100% for process that I do not know of.

[image: First PC]

[image: Second PC]

Comment: It's malware. [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit)

Comment: @gronostaj I have scanned using clamscan and rkhunter but found nothing

Comment: You've found it in `htop`, you don't need another piece of software to tell you it's there. It's time to make sure your backups are up to date and restorable, then nuke the OS and reinstall from scratch.